# Emacs Lisp - Should you unset keys before setting them?

Tags: emacs, elisp

If I'm going to redefine a key, should I call `(global-unset-key (kbd "key-combo"))`, or does using the function `global-set-key` automatically call that for me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is absolutely no need to unset the key before setting it.

This is similar to variable setting in any programming language: you do not need to do `foo = NULL` before `foo = x`. This comparison is closer than one might think because `(global-unset-key k)` is the same as `(global-set-key k nil)`.

Answer (score 3):

Like sds saied, `global-unset-key` actually calls `global-set-key`:

```
(defun global-unset-key (key)
  "Remove global binding of KEY.
KEY is a string or vector representing a sequence of keystrokes."
  (interactive "kUnset key globally: ")
  (global-set-key key nil))
```

so there is no real difference between set and unset key actually.